# Comment-Syntax for askubuntu / stackexchange ?

Tags: feature-request

A few minutes ago, I just had my first comment.
Id like to make bulletlists, due to better readabilty.
But I failed. I tried: "-" "*" and numbers.

So is formatting disabled in comments ?

Answer (score 2):

Comments only have a bit of formatting allowed because the purpose of the site is to have good answers, not necessarily comments.

If you're leaving a comment to your existing answer, just edit it to make it better. If it's not, consider expanding your thought of what you would have made in a comment and add another answer to the question.